# Select max date in two columns with group by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to select all columns form extract table where I need to select the values which are with latest Upload_Date and latest date_modification among ID column. Basically I want to select max dated values in each ID.

Tried with below qeuiry but getting error as "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

```
SELECT *
   FROM public.extract
  WHERE extract."Upload_Date" = (( SELECT max(extract."Upload_Date")
           FROM public.extract))  
           AND extract."date_modification" = (( 
               SELECT max(extract."date_modification")
                FROM public.extract
            group by extract."ID" ));
```

I am new to postgresql. It will be helpful can someone suggest where I am making mistake.

Sample Data looks like

[image]

Expected output is like this

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question to make it more clear what you want here.

Comment: Updated the sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID) *
FROM public.extract
ORDER BY ID, Upload_Date DESC, date_modification DESC;
```

Comment: I want to select all the columns of extract table with latest date in Upload_Date column and latest date in date_modification columns, my table is having around 40 columns. where in each upload date value has multiple date_modification values.

Comment: @ParthaSarathi Let us know if the answer works for you after your edits.

Comment: Yes. It is working absolutely as expected after edit.